# Help with 2s BMS charger/discharger board

Tags: bms

I have built li-ion battery pack  with 2x 18650 cells and 2s BMS board as shown in the picture. When I measure voltage across B- and B+, I’m getting 7.9v, same if I measure voltage across P+ and B-, but I’m getting only 0.1v when I measure voltage across P+ and P-. What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: The protect circuit is triggered. Have you tried to charge the battery or put some load on it? Did you connect the three wires in the order defined in board manual?

Comment: Amazing! Charging board solved the problem. Thanks a lot!